# How to make a new window from pushButton

Tags: qt

Is there any other way to make a new window from onther window? open->New project->Gui Type->mainWindow.cpp. it will make the winodw and i wish to the push button on it. iwant to open a new window after On_click (). how do i will achieve it can any body explain me we are facing a lot of problem

Comment: you should post your code here and also mention what kind of issue you are facing

Comment: I think if you are using Qt and you have not yet learned how to use signal/slot connections, then you may be facing more problems than to which you are even aware. As suggested by @Kunal, you must show us what you have tried and where it is failing. As it stands right now, it sounds like you want a tutorial on how to connect signals to slots.

Answer (score 0):

You should connect `QPushButton's clicked()` signal to your slot, in implementation of slot, you can create new Widget and show it.